# Binding a text file information to DataGrid using Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am making an *AddressBook* program in WPF and I want to bind my `DataGridColumn` from a text file having contacts information.
But, I don't know how to do it

Here's my ViewModel(ContactsViewModel.cs):

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System.Windows;

namespace AddressBook {
public class ContactsViewModel : Screen {
   //What to do here ?
}
}
```

Here's the XAML Code(ContactsView.xaml):

```
<UserControl x:Class="AddressBook.ContactsView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <DataGrid FontSize="16" CanUserResizeColumns="False" SelectedIndex="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Name" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Mobile No." Width="170"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Email" Width="200"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Address" Width="240"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</UserControl>
```

And Here's my text file(Contacts.txt):

```
Humayun 032121352643 nexgenking@gmail.com A-312 korangi karachi,
Jahangir 03212515332 mawahid02@gmailcom A-584 korangi karachi
pakistan,
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a property of collection in the ViewModel and Give the same name to the control name property. Refer the below code.

```
 <DataGrid FontSize="16" x:Name="List" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" SelectedIndex="1">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Name" Width="150" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Mobile No." Width="170" Binding="{Binding MobileNo}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Email" Width="200" Binding="{Binding Email}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn FontSize="14" Header="Address" Width="240" Binding="{Binding Address}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

public class ContactsViewModel : Screen 
{
    public ContactsViewModel()
    {
        string str = File.ReadAllText("Contacts.txt");
        string[] strContracts = str.Split(',');
        foreach (var item in strContracts)
        {
            string[] fields = item.Trim().Split(' ');
            _list.Add(new Contact() { Name = fields[0],MobileNo= fields[1],Email=fields[2],Address=fields[3] });
        }
    }
    private IObservableCollection<Contact> _list = new BindableCollection<Contact>();
    public IObservableCollection<Contact> List
    {
        get { return _list; }
        set
        {
            _list = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => List);
        }
    }
}

public class Contact
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }

    private string address;

    public string Address
    {
        get { return address; }
        set { address = value; }
    }

    private string email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }

    private string mobileNo;

    public string MobileNo
    {
        get { return mobileNo; }
        set { mobileNo = value; }
    }


}
```

In this example List is the Property name of the collection as well as the name of the Datagrid. In the Constructor of the viewmodel has the parsing logic of the file data and make a collection object out of it